# How to download large CSV file?

Tags: java, apache-poi, export-to-excel, jxl

My application requires a reporting facility in excel/csv format. In case of large report, the generated CSV is corrupt. Though i am able to e-mail the generated CSV using smtp.

I tried changing the following with no lead, your help on this is appreciated

1. Change the library to POI
2. Changed the library to JXL
3. Monitored if there is a memory leakage

This is a web based application and the code is written in JSP.

Comment: Please clarify on "large" and "corrupt". And do you have problems with generating the file or with downloading it?

Comment: How does it matter if it's CSV or random data? Couldn't you just use http, for example?

Comment: @Andreas_D: "Large" is the dataset that we get from sql query while Currupt is the generated CSV which does not have all the records, rather it has repeated records, i.e. initially 100 are printed than again same hundred records, while resultset has 500 records

Comment: Are you 100% positive, that the resultset has 500 different records? It sounds like a problem with your algorithm - like you try to process in portions of 100 records and accidentally miss to update a pointer...

Answer (score 0):

POI is mainly for MS office formats like xls, xlsx, doc. JXL is also for xls files. You should use a framework which is for CSV like [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).